# using bootstrap3 for angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am use angular4.0. I am use bootstrap3.3.7.

I succeeded in using bootstrap Button and Grid.
But, DropDown & Datepicker can not be used well.

install package.

- intl@1.2.5
- bootstrap@3.3.7
- ng-bootstrap

**angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
 "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
 "styles.css"
],
```

**app.component.html**

```
 {{title}}

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

This src makes button and dropdown.
Button is successful.
But DropDown is failed.

Do you know why dropDown and datepicker can not be used?

Comment: Angular 4.0? Wow, that's new to me.

Comment: Probably because bootstrap has no `dropdown-item` class

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io), you should know that they're using Bootstrap 4, so there might be some class misnaming. If you want Angular 2 library for Bootstrap 3, you might check [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) from Valor Software.

Comment: thank you for comment.

I changed the package.
・intl@1.2.5 
・bootstrap@3.3.7 
・ng2-bootstrap@1.1.14
But the situation does not change.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Adnan says, "ng2-bootstrap" was renamed to "ngx-bootstrap" ;) Be aware in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

issue is with bootstrap.css. so use the (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)cdn link in your index.hhtml.since there is no npm package for bootstrap4